# Redirecting to both screen and file

Tags: bash, io-redirection, exec, tee

I'd like to redirect all of the output of the commands I ran to a file, in addition to having them printed on the screen.

I want this to happen automatically, I don't want to pipe into `tee` everytime I do this.

I tried `exec | tee file`, but it doesn't work. How do I go about doing this?

This is Bash, so `PROMPT_COMMAND` is also available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
exec > >(tee logfile) 2>&1
```

This would redirect the shell's output and error streams to the process substitution `>(tee logfile)`, which would save it in `logfile` while also outputting them to the terminal.

As user mosvy correctly points out [in comments below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519800/redirecting-to-both-screen-and-file/519804?noredirect=1#comment960586_519804),  any program output would be produced as if redirected to a file. If a utility makes a difference between outputting to a file and to a terminal device, then there will be a difference in output from what you may expect. Some programs that require a terminal may not work at all.

You may also use the `script` utility which by itself starts an interactive shell that is logged to a file.  See the manual for `script`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to include the exit status of each command in the first option?

Comment: @exit_status I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.

Comment: If you do that, many programs will start acting differently because their stdout/stderr no longer goes to a tty. For instance, `ls` will stop printing by columns.

Comment: @mosvy Absolutely true. Any program output would be produced as when redirected to a file.  If a utility makes a difference between a file and a terminal device, then there will be a difference in output. Some programs that require a terminal would not work at all.

Comment: @Kusalananda More specifically, I'd like to have a log of what command was run and its exit status (`$?` ). To be even more precise, I actually want to have a log consisting of: command, exit status, directory where the command was ran and all output.

Comment: @exit_status That's quite different from what's currently in the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, sorry. I just meant to ask about including the exit status somehow, if it's an easy adaptation of the current answer. If it isn't, I'll ask in another question.